# Can't post question while question banned after 6 months of last question

Tags: support, post-ban

So apparently I'm question banned on Stack Overflow. My last question was posted on Dec 18 2020, over 6 months ago, and from what I understood you get a temporary lift of your ban after 6 months after your last post, yet that hasn't happened.

I never deleted any post I made, I have a couple downvoted posts but I always try to provide as much detail and finesse to my questions as I can, so I was wondering what my case is about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: "My last question was posted on Dec 18 2020" Your last question is from [April 7th](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66992293/11682469).

Comment: My profile's default question order was "Votes", not time... Doesn't make much sense, but question answered, I guess.

Comment: You have the following 3 deleted questions: [Q1](//stackoverflow.com/q/43279280), [Q2](//stackoverflow.com/q/39878668), and [Q3](//stackoverflow.com/q/37150487).

Comment: Can't even see that on my profile, not even with the [reputation workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140683/allow-banned-users-to-see-their-own-deleted-posts/333518#333518). Question's answered anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jeanne for pointing out my actual last post's date (Stack Overflow orders posts in the profile by voted on default), and to Makyen for showing me my deleted posts (only 10k+ reputation users can see all deleted posts of a user, regular users can only see posts deleted in the last 60 days).

Comment: "*only 10k+ reputation users can see all deleted posts of a user*" no, 10k users cannot *easily* find all deleted posts. Moderators have easier access to that. You can view your own deleted posts using the query `user:me deleted:yes` [here is the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3Ayes). Regular users cannot search for non-own deleted posts. The `deleted:yes` filter automatically restricts to only posts by the current user. Which makes the `user:me` filter superfluous.

Comment: I had already tried that search, but [it only yielded the visible posts](https://i.imgur.com/rWU00jQ.png), no deleted ones.

Comment: I see. Actually, you need [the 10k privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) in order to search *any* deleted posts. Says so [at the bottom of the search documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). I find this strange - you can only see your own deleted posts anyway... (unless you're a diamond mod).